# count of sublists containing item for all items

Tags: python, counter

I'm looking for a more efficient/pythonic way of doing this.

```
l = [[0,0],[1,0],[4,5,1],[2,3,5],[0,4]]

set_l = set([i for sl in l for i in sl])

sublists_containing_item_count = [sum([1 for x in l if i in x]) for i in set_l]

count_dict = dict(zip(set_l,sublists_containing_item_count))

count_dict

{0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 2}
```

Comment: my list was too simple to capture the intended result.  I want to count the sublists not items in flattened list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `collections.Counter` to produce a dict of counts and use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to flatten your nested list

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> import itertools

>>> l = [[0],[1,0],[4,5,1],[2,3,5],[0,4]]
>>> c = Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(l))
>>> c
Counter({0: 3, 1: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1})
```

Comment: this solution doesn't produce the intended result.  see edit.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get efficient/Pythonic ways.

## collections.Counter

```
from collections import Counter

l = [[0],[1,0],[4,5,1],[2,3,5],[0,4]]

count_dict = Counter([i for sl in l for i in sl])
```

So very Pythonic.

## collections.defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [[0],[1,0],[4,5,1],[2,3,5],[0,4]]
count_dict = defaultdict(int)

for sl in l:
    for i in sl:
        count_dict[i] += 1
```

So very simple dict.

## Short code with sum() and collections.Counter()

```
from collections import Counter
l = [[0],[1,0],[4,5,1],[2,3,5],[0,4]]
count_dict = Counter(sum(l,[]))
```

## result

`print(count_dict)`

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford to use packages outside the standard library, then `more_itertools` could provide a more readable solution:

```py
from more_itertools import flatten
from collections import Counter

l = [[0],[1,0],[4,5,1],[2,3,5],[0,4]]
c = Counter(flatten(l))
print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Counter** [**`update`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.update) method to add/update
the count as you add more iterables to it.

> Elements are counted from an iterable or added-in from another mapping
> (or counter). Like dict.update() but adds counts instead of replacing
> them. Also, the iterable is expected to be a sequence of elements, not
> a sequence of (key, value) pairs.

```
from collections import Counter

l = [[0], [1, 0], [4, 5, 1], [2, 3, 5], [0, 4]]
count = Counter()  # initialize an empty counter

for lst in l:
    count.update(lst)
print(dict(count))
```

**Output:**

```
{0: 3, 1: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say that this is more "efficient", but I think it's safe to say that it's more Pythonic. Use a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> l = [[0],[1,0],[4,5,1],[2,3,5],[0,4]]
>>> {i:sum([sl.count(i) for sl in l]) for i in set([i for sl in l for i in sl])}
{0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from the explanation, you are trying to count the occurrence of each number.

Here is a way you can do it using python's inbuild func.

```py
from collections import Counter

l = [[0],[1,0],[4,5,1],[2,3,5],[0,4]]

arr = [i for sl in l for i in sl]

count_dict = Counter(arr)

print(count_dict)
```